# how to choose family in CVgam in r?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, generalized-additive-model, exponential-family

I'm trying to run a repeated k-fold cross validation of my GAM model, but I can't specify my family in CVgam in R. I want to compare poisson GAM and Negative binomial GAM.  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: From what package is `CVgam()`?

Comment: It is from gamclass.